# Node.js Posting

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

This is in my app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

This is my post method

```
app.post('/data', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var age = req.body.age;
    console.log(name);
});
```

and this is the post I'm trying to use:

```
$.post( "http://localhost:3000/data", { name: "John", age: 25} );
```

and this is the error I get:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/data 404
```

Can anyone point out the stupid mistake I'm making? Thanks everyone

Comment: Is the node server running?  What port is it listeniing to?

Comment: Are you running another process which is answering to that port, or forgot to reload the server after you saved the route for `/data`?

Comment: Running on the correct port? Using Express.js? Is that the only post handler in the server for '/data'? Could you put a full running node.js snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: This is not the cause for the 404, but your `app.post()` handler needs to send something to the `res` object as in `res.send("ok");` or `res.json({status: "ok"});` or something.